convert imagemagick output to python pillow code
I have some tiff images, one example:
$ identify 015.tiff
015.tiff[0] TIFF 3925x5978 3925x5978+0+0 8-bit sRGB 10.6771MiB 0.000u 0:00.002
015.tiff[1] TIFF 1962x2989 1962x2989+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
015.tiff[2] TIFF 981x1494 981x1494+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
015.tiff[3] TIFF 490x747 490x747+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
015.tiff[4] TIFF 245x373 245x373+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
015.tiff[5] TIFF 122x186 122x186+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001
015.tiff[6] TIFF 61x93 61x93+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001

I can convert them to JPG with imagemagick:
convert -quiet 015.tiff -quality 90 output_file.jpg

The output:
-rw-r--r-- 1 incognito incognito 4384574 Jun  7 14:17 output_file-0.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 incognito incognito 1393899 Jun  7 14:17 output_file-1.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 incognito incognito  424514 Jun  7 14:17 output_file-2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 incognito incognito  141932 Jun  7 14:17 output_file-3.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 incognito incognito   57152 Jun  7 14:17 output_file-4.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 incognito incognito   33581 Jun  7 14:17 output_file-5.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 incognito incognito   27749 Jun  7 14:17 output_file-6.jpg

I need the second image output_file-1.jpg that would be 015.tiff[1] TIFF 1962x2989 1962x2989+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.001 in the tiff file.
I'm trying to do the same in python, below my code so far:
import os
from PIL import Image

yourpath = os.getcwd()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[1].lower() == ".tiff":
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".jpg"):
                print("A jpeg file already exists for %s" % name)
            # If a jpeg is *NOT* present, create one from the tiff.
            else:
                outfile = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".jpg"
                try:
                    im = Image.open(os.path.join(root, name))
                    print("Generating jpeg for %s" % name)
                    im.thumbnail(im.size)
                    im.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=90)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

The output:
$ identify 015.jpg
015.jpg JPEG 3925x5978 3925x5978+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3.60074MiB 0.000u 0:00.000

What should I do to have the same output with, in this case (that may vary, so I can't just hardencode the resolution) 1962x2989 resolution?
